# How to set the Loglevel for a JUnit Test

Tags: java, maven, logging, junit, java.util.logging

I am using java logging in my classes.

Example:

```
public class MyClass  {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
    ....
}
```

When I am writing a JUnit Test for that class, I would like to set the Loglevel to 'FINE'. I tried:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws PluginException {
    Logger.getGlobal().setLevel(Level.FINE);
    ....
}
```

But this has no effect. 
How can I control the loglevel in a JUnit Test when using Java Logging?
I am running my tests using Maven.

Comment: How are you running unit tests? maven or some other way?

Comment: Try `Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINE)`.

Answer (score 8):

This is the simplest, most generic way I've found to set the `java.util.logging` level for JUnit tests.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest
{
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass()
    {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", ClassLoader.getSystemResource("logging.properties").getPath());
    }

    @Test
    public void test00a()
    {
        Logger.getLogger(MyTest.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, "J.U.L. test");
    }
}
```

In `src/test/resources` create `logging.properties` ([`.level` must be the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501521/2074605)):

```
.level=FINEST
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
```

When you run the unit test(s) in this class, you should see:

> May 01, 2017 12:17:12 PM MyTest test00a
>
> FINE: J.U.L. test

Answer (score 1):

Logger.getLogger() documentation:

> Find or create a logger for a named subsystem.  If a logger has already been created with the given name it is returned.  Otherwise a new logger is created.

In your case, Logger.getLogger() with the same name gives you the same logger-instance. Therefore, you can get the logger and set its level with

```
@Before
public void setup() throws PluginException {
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.FINE);
    ...
}
```

Just make sure to set it back in the @After-method later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this did not work. Maybe I need to set also some additional global log level? I debugged the code and my class is now logging - but not into the standard  output. I am running tests with Maven.

Comment: @Ralph See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43722641/2074605) for a complete example that works at the class level.

Comment: If you using SLF4J you will not be able to set the level. You can work around this by casting the logger to its underlying implementation. In my case that was Logback (Spring Boot's default).
```
 @BeforeEach
 public void setup() {
  ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = (Logger) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
  logger.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I defined a custom JUnit 4 rule to disable logs for a specific test:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogLevelRule extends TestWatcher {

  private Level oldLevel;
  private final Class clazz;
  private final String levelString;

  @Override
  protected void starting(Description description) {
    oldLevel = Logger.getLogger(clazz).getLevel();
    Logger.getLogger(clazz).setLevel(Level.toLevel(levelString));
  }

  @Override
  protected void finished(Description description) {
    Logger.getLogger(clazz).setLevel(oldLevel);
  }
}
```

This can then be enabled by declaring a `@Rule` of `@ClassRule` in the particular test:

```java
  @ClassRule
  public static LogLevelRule logLevelRule = new LogLevelRule(MyClass.class, "OFF");
```