# Java Logger: Can't set log level in logger.properties file

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have a java project that I use maven to build. 
I am using **`java.util.logging.Logger`** in my project and would like to configure it using a `logger.properties` file (not command line).

I created a **`logger.properties`** file like this:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=WARNING

java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%4$s] %5$s %n

java.util.logging.config.file="../../results/api.log"
```

Here are the problems that I'm having:

1. **`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` is WORKING**. When I change the format here, I see the change immediately in my project. So I know that at least I am importing the file correctly.
2. **`.level` is NOT working**. I've tried changing it to `info`, `finest`, `warning`, etc. but after I change it, I still see all the INFO messages even if I told it not to show INFO.
3. **`java.util.logging.config.file` is NOT working**. I kind of expected this one not to work because it is a relative path. Anyone know how I can resolve the relative path name in the properties file?

---

## Solution

I needed to move the `.level` to the top, like this:

**logger.properties**

```
.level=WARNING

handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%4$s] %5$s %n
```

Then, in order to save results to "api.log", I did this in my code:

**RequestHelper.java**

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class RequestHelper {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( RequestHelper.class.getName() );

    protected RequestHelper() {
        //SET LOGGER TO OUTPUT TO "../../results/api.log"
        //Logs will ALSO output to console.
        String result_file = getNormalizedAbsolutePath("../../results/api.log");
        Handler fh = new FileHandler(result_file);
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
    }

    public static String getNormalizedAbsolutePath(String fileName) {
        String path;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            path = file.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warning("Error while computing the canonical path of file: " + fileName);
            path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return FilenameUtils.normalize(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set -Djava.util.logging.config.file="logging.properties" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess.  From the documentation:

> All properties whose names end with ".level" are assumed to define log levels for Loggers. Thus "foo.level" defines a log level for the logger called "foo" and (recursively) for any of its children in the naming hierarchy. **Log Levels are applied in the order they are defined in the properties file. Thus level settings for child nodes in the tree should come after settings for their parents.**

Try setting `.level` first, before you define any of the handlers.  If you set the root logger level first, the loggers you define afterwards will inherit the root log level.

Also:

> A property "config". This property is intended to allow arbitrary configuration code to be run.

`java.util.logging.config.file` is a system property, and won't work in the config file.  Try just using "config".

Comment: Wow yup you got it! I just needed to move the ".level" line up to the top! Works now ty ^-^