# How to configure J.U.L. logging during JUnit tests?

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j, java.util.logging

I have the same problem as this: [How to set the log level to DEBUG during Junit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778026/how-to-set-the-log-level-to-debug-during-junit-tests) - except I'm working with `java.util.logging`, not Log4j.

Specifically, I'm converting an existing (Maven-built) application from Log4j to `java.util.logging`, in order to comply with a customer requirement (not negotiable). Everything uses SLF4J, so code changes are minimal. There are over a thousand test classes, spread across a few modules; we currently have a `log4j.properties` file in the `src/test/resources` of those modules to customize the log output of the tests.

I think it's important for log output to be easily customizable for tests: if a developer breaks a test and wants to read the log output, I'd prefer they locally tweak the log config than start messing with the (carefully chosen) log levels in the code, leading to "everything logged at info" syndrome. Note that I want the test log config to apply to "the test+application code when executed under test conditions".

I don't want to add log settings to each and every Test class (as suggested here: [How to set the Loglevel for a JUnit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566865/how-to-set-the-loglevel-for-a-junit-test)), because of the large number of tests. It seems like the wrong solution.  I also don't want to go editing the JVM's `logging.properties` file, as that would affect everything. This app isn't the only thing I do. I'd also have to get everyone else to make the same changes.

The existing system works because Log4j picks up `/log4j.properties` from the classpath. *Is there an equivalent mechanism for `java.util.logging`?*

Current thinking: add a `logging.properties` file to replace the existing config, and try and hack the Maven config to set the `java.util.logging.config.file` param to point at it. Is there a neater way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a neater way?

That is probably the most [reliable method to set the logging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441467/use-of-readconfiguration-method-in-logging-activities/36069135#36069135).

> Is there an equivalent mechanism for `java.util.logging`?

Configuration options are listed in the [java.util.logging.LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) documentation.  You can:

1. Set the `java.util.logging.config.file` property and use a properties file.
2. Set the `java.util.logging.config.class` property and create a class file with a no argument constructor to execute any code you desire to manually configure the loggers.
3. Use [LogManager.readConfiguration(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration-java.io.InputStream-) and [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to load a new configuration.  This logic can be combined with `java.util.logging.config.class` property too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Hopefully I get to try it this week, if I can fight off the clouds of distractions....

Comment: Ok, I finally got to play with it, and I configured Maven - in the project-wide pom - to add the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property to surefire. I'll add a note to my question to show the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A project-wide [`src/test/resources/logging.properties`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43722641/2074605) can be set specifically for unit testing via the [`java.util.logging.config.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) System property using a single line in your `@BeforeClass` method:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", ClassLoader.getSystemResource("logging.properties").getPath());
```

Comment: When you say "in your @BeforeClass method" - I think I need to do that in every single test class, is that right? Is that better than setting it in the surefire config in the pom?

Comment: @SusanW Yes, each test class would need it in `@BeforeClass`. You could probably set up something in a test suite as well, but all I needed was a one-liner that would give me control over logging level when running unit tests. You only need the one `logging.properties` file, but you could also do that on a per-class basis as well, just change the resource name or use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream('logging.properties')` or something similar. As far as better/worse than other methods, I use Ivy instead of Maven and I prefer to keep clean separation between JUnit and Ivy.